# Is it possible to mark my own question as duplicate of another?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I just realized one of my questions has a perfect duplicate, and I want to mark it as a duplicate and give the duplicate question link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes)

Comment: That duplicate is only to *confirm*, in the case that your question is already marked as a duplicate. This question (might) talk about the case where it isn't marked.

Answer (score 11):

Yes it is! Just click the "close" link underneath your question, and follow the instructions.

Sometimes you have used such different wordings that it's impossible to find the question, only to have users point it out to you 5 minutes later. I even have had this problem myself, but fortunately, you can help clean it up as well!

Comment: [If you have above 10k on SU](http://superuser.com/questions/126700/how-can-i-keep-several-columns-always-visible-while-scrolling-in-excel), you can go and laugh at me now...

Comment: "Close" doesn't appear for me 2011-08-25, but "Flag" did and has a flow to provide an exact duplicate link.

Comment: [You need 250 rep to vote to close your own questions](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes), which is much less than the 3000 you need to close other users' questions, but still significant. The system could be explained better.

Comment: There is no "close" anymore.

Comment: @DanM. There is on my own question on StackOverflow. Not sure where you're looking

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if there are no answers yet, and you actually think that future visitors will more likely first find the duplicate (instead of your new question): simply click the "delete" link underneath your question.

Comment: It's not necessarily bad to have a duplicate, because with the different wording you create new linkbait for us on Google :-)

Comment: True, @Ivo, hence my *"if [..] you actually think that future visitors will more likely first find the duplicate (instead of your new question)"*.

Answer (score 1):

You can also click the little `Flag` link under your question.  Follow the directions and it will appear on a special list shown only to people with over 10K rep.  These people have the power to close your question as a duplicate which is something you cannot do by yourself(you can delete your own posts by yourself however).

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before, time and again. One reason why this often happens is that the "Questions with similar titles" listing doesn't show as many similar questions as the "Related" tab, once the question is saved. That way, it sometimes takes me to write the whole question body before I realise that a question was asked before.

Nevertheless, a duplicate question adds more relevance to the original one, and may add more information to it through links. So your work is not "for nothing". Besides that, it will be easier in the future to find duplicates if there are already two questions dealing with the same problem.

So, keep doing it!